# how do i make the "contact us" on a page created not to display

Tags: forms

when creating pages, the title normally show as a link and as a title on the page it displayed when click on. My question is how do i remove the title from displaying on my page. for example when a page like "contact us" is created, the page itself will have "contact us" display in either h1 or h2 tag. how do i make the "contact us" on the page not to display.

Answer (score 1):

Set the title as 'Contact'. Then use the following code:

```
add_filter('the_title','remove_title');

function remove_title($title) {
    if( !is_page('Contact') ) {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Put this code in your `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

A code I often use (as an example is as follows):

```
<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
<h1><?php _e('My Custom Page Title', '<YOUR LOC DOMAIN>'); ?></h1> <!-- Or leave blank -->
<?php else: ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will allow you to use whatever page title you wish or none at all on certain pages. You can search the WordPress Codex for alternatives to `is_front_page` such as a page or ID.

Comment: Do you really use so messy code? If you use it so often, couldn't you tidy it up a little bit? (see my edits).